# Is it possible to fake momentum by tracking an objects last known positions?

Tags: post-processing

Basically I am making a melee combat system. I want to be able to apply force based on where/how things are hit.
I am NOT using physics simulations for this, which is why I cannot just rely on that.
Instead, can I track the part of the sword that hits the target somehow, to work it's average momentum/direction of attack?
I tried by just using the last frame position and the current frame position, but this doesn't give a great angle (as the sword rotates a lot, it always taps it towards the player, when really all the momentum is going directly left).
Is there a formula for working this out? Or is it as something as simple as just totally up the directional changes each frame, with some kind of decay time.

Comment: [Verlet Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration) uses current & previous position instead of velocity, so if you can generate an acceleration term from your impacts then that might be usable - have you looked into that? It sounds like rotational effects are significant in your case though. Would you be able to provide an image sequence/video/diagram of a typical or problem case so we can better visualize what we're dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you use 'post-processing' tag? Anyway:

I would start with why you want to do this with that kind of precision.

Just to compare, you could consider a simpler system such as "when hit, the enemy is knocked back/up at a 30-degree angle." This system is easy to implement and predictable for the player. So for example maybe the player knows how to try to set up an enemy to knock them into that pit or exploding barrel or man-eating plant's mouth or whatever.

Making a more realistic system that depends on the exact frame of impact might sound cool, but are you expecting the player to understand what's happening? Are you expecting them to utilize the differences as a mechanism of control? That second one is critical because now you're opening like 1-frame timing windows for the player to achieve some exact knockback direction.

In this most recent Ludum Dare I made a tennis/arkanoid mashup and it's fairly tricky to get the player feeling in control of the angle of a shot. If that's a key element of your game it will require a lot of focus and feedback... for example in my tennis game I have a fairly intense slo-mo moment for 8 frames when the player impacts the ball, so their eye can really observe and they feel the weight. Then I have a directional impact flash that lingers so they can observe an arrow that shows them the vector they achieved. The ball also takes on a temporary trails effect so they can see the movement off the racket for a moment. Still, only some players felt their aim was strong and a number never even realized how or to what extent they could control the angle of impact.

My point is that you will need to treat it carefully if you expect control of knockback direction based on momentum of an arcing sword to be important. If it's not important, perhaps you will be better off with something extremely simple and thus easily understandable, predictable, and reliable. If the simple system feels wrong in a few cases, you can always have a couple of simple checks, like do this if the enemy is standing, that if he is caught midair while jumping, or something.

Good luck!